# fundamental theorem derivative inside integral single variable

Tags: calculus

So the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt = f(x)
$$

but what would 
$$
\int_{a}^{x} \frac{d}{dx}  f(t)dt = \_?
$$

in the single variable case.  I assume $\frac{d}{dx}f(t)=0$ because $t$ is not a function of $x$ in general. Then integrating with respect to $t$ from $a$ to $x$ gives an arbitrary constant, which doesn't make sense.....

What am I doing wrong? Is there a rule I'm violating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f(t)$ doesn't depend on $x$,
$$\int_a^x \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(t)\mathrm d t=0.$$

Comment: i thought so. You will get the answer in 10 minutes. Ill edit this comment when I do

Comment: You're forgetting that $x$ is the upper limit of integration.  So $\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ DOES depend on $x$

Comment: @cpiegore: You probably should read the question of the OP.

Comment: @cpiegore It would be $∫_a^x(\frac{d}{dx}f(t))dt=0$, I think so the integral would integrate over the area within the parenthesis, which would be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is due to a bad use of Leibniz notation:
$$\int_{a}^{x}f'(t)\,dt = f(x) - f(a).$$